# Drag text from terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is there anyway I can drag the text out from terminal and release in some other terminal or text file?

I am asking for a laptop, where a touchpad is used.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101145/select-and-drag-paste-in-terminal

Comment: In Laptop Please.

Comment: Why not copy/paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @souravc suggested, instead of actually visually dragging it, you can copy paste using your mouse/touchpad and without involving the context-menu.

To copy select the text to be copied by dragging the mouse.

**On a desktop:** To paste, middle click where you want to paste.

**On laptop:** Press both the left click and right click together.

Comment: yes it works nicely.

Comment: @rajagenupula: While copying or while pasting? Do you have any shortcut set for any of these key combinations? Which version of ubuntu and gnome-terminal are you using?

Comment: @rajagenupula: Please answer all the question, would make it easier to solve.

Comment: @rajagenupula: Can you please come over chat here:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13077/with-rajagenupula

Comment: its not allowing me to login into your chat room.

Comment: Thank you for answering.+1, I will clarify my doubt later,:)